# Grid or Table using Angular 6

Tags: grid, angular6

I'm tasked to create a table that will display data from an endpoint.  The table must be very responsive in that a user can "click" to remove rows or columns from the view (collapsable) and re-add them if they choose. Would you use a Table or a Grid to accomplish this task? Or maybe something entirely different? I'm using Angular 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For table or grid you can either use angular material (table) https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Or something like bootstrap4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Both work great with angular.

Answer (score 1):

for the table creation and to maintain the table you can use the AG-Grid (https://ag-grid.com) this will help you to create the table with your own customized table. Or if it's only for a table creation you can use the bootstrap tables and angular material table among that I will suggest you angular material it's more easy and simple to implement.